# How to handle 'string/number or undefined' is not assignable to type string/number when using global variable as way to store data

Tags: reactjs, zustand

**I know there are many ways to handle this if this situation only happens a few times.**

Let me illustrate my situation

I have a people management app and I am using **zustand** to have a global variable to store my data.

**Here is a example of my global variable data type**

```
interface IClient { 
data?: string
telephone?: number
content?: string
client?:number
...
...

}
```

As we can see, in fact all property are set as optional coz some can only be set during the app instead of at the beginning.

****However**, problem happens in my last component, which is to generate a report about the everything.**

While I import this global variable in this last componment, I supposed have all data input already.

**However, when I want to use them as if I am so sure they are non null and non undefined,
I have to say client!.data! or client.telephone! or client.content!. many many times , otherwise I would get a ts warning**

I knew that alternatively I can use  ***type-guard or nullish coalescing or if statement.*** But still, I still have to do the remedy whenever I try to access the global variable. But there are many places that I need to access it. So, I will have a lot of these kind of tricks in my code.

Is there a way that I can do it once and then I can just access the global variable without having to tell ts that it is non-null and non-undefined?

**Disable ts checking is not my preference**

Comment: You can make a type that will make all fields of IClient as required. `const client = state.client as Required<IClient>`.